# how to control request encoding outside of code in .net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am having issues with my requests being encoded differently in my prod environment vs dev.

in dev the request from my mvc app to my rest service is coming in as
dev - ?name=Hörberg
and in prod it is being encoded like this
Prod - ?name=H%25u00f6rberg

the code is the same so I am thinking it may be a configuration somewhere. I couldn't find anything in the machine config. Maybe there is an environment variable for this?

both of my web.configs have this in them

`<globalization culture="en-US" uiCulture="en" requestEncoding="UTF-8" responseEncoding="UTF-8" fileEncoding="UTF-8" />`

i am on .net v4.0, mvc5

Comment: This has to do with special characters - perhaps you can add a correction layer when receiving the request, replacing the html values "%xxxx" by the corresponding character.

Comment: Also, what are the differences between your prod and dev environments? are you using the same web browsers/data sources etc?

Comment: I am not quite sure why this is a concern, can you perhaps elaborate @mingle? Because MVC automatically decodes action parameters as the actions are called.

Comment: `Windows > Control Panel > Region > Administrative` make sure that both dev and prod have the same settings. As it seems Prod cannot process Unicode characters. So, check the server localization.

Comment: The url for rest is constructed in the MVC Action methods? If so, is the MVC application getting this url in correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is URL encoded,try to use:
var decodedName = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(name)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this has to do with system settings, rather than any encoding/decoding. Validate the regional settings in both dev and prod environment. If you want prod to behave like dev, then make the settings same as dev in prod environment.